# Date and Time Format Problems in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datetime-format

I am trying to truncate the seconds part from the current Date

```
  Dim nowTime As DateTime = Now.ToShortTimeString
```

The above code shows time in the format

> hh:mm:ss

I want it in the format

> hh:mm

---

The Date Time Picker shows date like this

> 5/ 1/2011

(There is a space before 5 and before 1)

```
 Dim nowTime As DateTime = Now.ToShortTimeString
```

The above code shows Date like this

> 5/1/2011

(There is no space before 5 or 1)

---

I am trying to compare the current Date and time with the Date and Time in  the database.

In the database I have saved the Date and Time as string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to apply a correct [FormatString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) with `DateTime.ToString()` like

```
dateValue.ToString("hh:mm")
```

and for the date:

```
Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

[more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: @Failed_Noob: You can extract whatever formatted string value you want using DateTime.ToString(format) ..

Answer (score 2):

```
String.Format("{0:HH:mm}", DateTime.Now)
```

Comment: its shows time in 24 hour clock, how to change t to 12 hour clock format ?

Comment: Figured it out `String.Format("{0:hh:mm}", DateTime.Now)`

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
String format = "What ever format you want"; // Examples: "hh:mm", "MM/dd/yyyy"

String value = youDateTimeObject.ToString(format);
```

---

[Read more about it](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/).